# Find max/mean in range defined by values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: example pic]I have a df as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size = (20, 1)),columns=['A'])
s = [0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,1,2,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,0]
df['B'] = s

>>> print(df)
    A  B
0   4  0
1   1  0
2   6  1
3   3  0
4   4  0
5   3  0
6   1  2
7   4  0
8   2  1
9   3  2
10  4  0
11  9  0
12  4  1
13  0  0
14  6  0
15  6  2
16  9  0
17  2  1
18  9  0
19  3  0
```

My goal is add two new columns, namely 'C_Max' and 'D_Mean'.

If the value of column B is 1, then the index from ‘1’ to the next occurrence of ‘2’ is [2:6], put the maximum value between [2:6] in column A into column C_Max at the same position with B1's 1, i.e. [2] in column C_Max, then average all the numbers [2:6] in column A, and put the result in the same position as column B in column D_Mean, that is, [2] in column D_mean. And so on.

Ignored if 2 does not appear after 1.The values of other cells in columns C_Max and D_min do not matter.

Desired output:

```
>>> df
    A  B  C_Max  D_Mean
0   4  0    NaN     NaN
1   1  0    NaN     NaN
2   6  1    6.0     3.4
3   3  0    NaN     NaN
4   4  0    NaN     NaN
5   3  0    NaN     NaN
6   1  2    NaN     NaN
7   4  0    NaN     NaN
8   2  1    3.0     2.5
9   3  2    NaN     NaN
10  4  0    NaN     NaN
11  9  0    NaN     NaN
12  4  1    6.0     4.0
13  0  0    NaN     NaN
14  6  0    NaN     NaN
15  6  2    NaN     NaN
16  9  0    NaN     NaN
17  2  1    NaN     NaN
18  9  0    NaN     NaN
19  3  0    NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Could you add your desired output for the sample input? The way you describe it is a bit confusing

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Sure, just add desired output in my post. The result I calculated through Excel, there may be errors in a hurry, I will check it again

Comment: Just simplified my data to make it look a little clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Setup:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4, 1, 6, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 9, 4, 0, 6, 6, 9, 2, 9, 3],
                   'B': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0]
                  })

B_groups = (df.B.eq(1) | df.B.shift().eq(2)).cumsum()
funcs = ["max", "mean"]
```

Merge the grouped and aggregated data with the original dataframe.
(Note how this is very maintainable – if you need additional metrics, just amend the `funcs` list.)

```py
df2 = df.merge(
    df.groupby(B_groups).A.agg(funcs),
    left_on=B_groups,
    right_index=True,
    ).drop("key_0", axis=1) # drop new column introduced by merge
```

And that is basically it. You get:

```py
>>> df2.head(10)
   A  B  max  mean
0  4  0    4   2.5
1  1  0    4   2.5
2  6  1    6   3.4
3  3  0    6   3.4
4  4  0    6   3.4
5  3  0    6   3.4
6  1  2    6   3.4
7  4  0    4   4.0
8  2  1    3   2.5
9  3  2    3   2.5
```

To get rid of the superfluous values, you can re-assign the two new columns, keeping everything up to the last
non-zero value in `B`.

```py
df2 = df2.loc[:df2.B[::-1].idxmax()]
df2[funcs] = df2.loc[df2.B.eq(1), funcs]
```

Final result:

```py
    A  B  max  mean
0   4  0  NaN   NaN
1   1  0  NaN   NaN
2   6  1  6.0   3.4
3   3  0  NaN   NaN
4   4  0  NaN   NaN
5   3  0  NaN   NaN
6   1  2  NaN   NaN
7   4  0  NaN   NaN
8   2  1  3.0   2.5
9   3  2  NaN   NaN
10  4  0  NaN   NaN
11  9  0  NaN   NaN
12  4  1  6.0   4.0
13  0  0  NaN   NaN
14  6  0  NaN   NaN
15  6  2  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! My only quibble is that you chose to chop off the end of the data (after the last `B==2`). Probably better to override from there with NaNs, rather than drop it

Comment: Very informative answer!

Answer (score 1):

The approach I took was to `groupby` beginnings and ends of the range - ie B equals 1 or 2. This actually created too many groups, since there are ranges in between groups, so we find the places where B = 2 (end of a streak), and take the values from there. Then we insert them at the beginnings of streaks (where B = 1).

Since there is an extra "streak beginning" (B = 1) without an end, we calculate this and pad with zero.

Hope this is clear:

```
df['C_Max'] = np.nan
df['D_Mean'] = np.nan

mask = np.cumsum(df.B.eq(1)) + np.cumsum(df.B.eq(2)).shift()
maxes = df.groupby(mask)['A'].cummax()
means = df.groupby(mask)['A'].transform('mean')

streak_ends = df.iloc[np.where(df.B.eq(2))[0]].index
pad_width = df.B.eq(1).sum() - df.B.eq(2).sum()

df.loc[df['B'].eq(1), 'C_Max'] = np.pad(maxes.loc[streak_ends].to_numpy(), (0, pad_width))
df.loc[df['B'].eq(1), 'D_Mean'] = np.pad(means.loc[streak_ends].to_numpy(), (0, pad_width))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works, but it's a little bit complicated. I'll see if I can wait for a simpler answer.